# Running my own programs on linux that run on qemu?

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, gdb, qemu

I have a PC that runs on Ubuntu 14 and kernel 3.14 compiled in it.
I installed **qemu** on it and activated it with the following command from shell:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel /home/user/linux-3.14.1/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.14.1+  -m 2048M --append "console=ttyS0 root=/dev/sda1 rw init=/bin/bash" -hda /home/user/qemu-file-img/myimage.img --enable-kvm -smp 4 -serial stdio -vga none -net none -s -S
```

Then from another shell I ran `gdb` and did these commands:

```
file vmlinux
targert remote :1234
```

And now I can break inside any function of the kernel and it's awesome.

My **question** though is, how do I run my **own** programs and then see what's happening inside the kernel? Right now it's just the kernel running its own process with nothing that I wrote myself. Just to make my point - I want to run a simple "Hello world" C program, run it, and see what's going inside the kernel while it runs it.

Thanks for your help.

OK I'll elaborate more ..

Its the first time I'm dealing with creating new filesystem img .. and dealing with qemu so I probably did things wrong:

I created the **disk img** like this:

```
  qemu-img create disk.img 512M
  mkfs.ext2 -F disk.img
```

About the **-initrd** flag , at the begining I put the path to **/boot/initrd.img-3.14.1+** , but than I saw in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBY9l97-lto) video that you should create initramfs like that :

```
./gen_init_cpio input | gzip >initramfs.img
```

where input file is of this structure :

```
dir /dev 0755 0 0
nod /dev/console 0600 0 0 c 5 1
dir /root 0700 0 0
dir /sbin 0755 0 0
file /sbin/kinit /usr/src/klibc/kinit/kinit 0755 0 0
```

I understood that through initramfs you can "share" your host files with the qemu running on the compiled kernel .

But again, Im really not sure of what Im doing . 
Eventualy, Thats the command I ran :

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel /home/user/linux-3.14.1/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -initrd /home/user/linux-3.14.1/usr/initramfs.img  -m 2048M --append 'console=ttyS0 root=/dev/sda rw init=/bin/bash' -hda /home/user/img_file_to_qemu2/disk.img --enable-kvm -smp 4 -serial stdio -vga none -net -s -S
```

and when I connected to qemu via gdb at the same way I mentioned before (target remote:1234) , I pressed "**continue**", and qemu started running the kernel and eventually It shows this :

```
0.466183] VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem) on device 8:0.
[    0.466672] devtmpfs: error mounting -2
[    0.467468] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1336K (ffffffff81d13000 - ffffffff81e61000)
[    0.467939] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 12288k
[    0.469480] Freeing unused kernel memory: 736K (ffff880001748000 - ffff880001800000)
[    0.470727] Freeing unused kernel memory: 580K (ffff880001b6f000 - ffff880001c00000)
[    0.471195] Failed to execute /bin/bash (error -2).  Attempting defaults...
[    0.471615] Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/init.txt for guidance.
[    0.472340] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.14.1+ #1
[    0.472340] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS Bochs 01/01/2011
[    0.472340]  0000000000000000 ffff88007cb67ec0 ffffffff8172f63d ffffffff81a5cce0
[    0.472340]  ffff88007cb67f38 ffffffff8172a78d ffffffff00000008 ffff88007cb67f48
[    0.472340]  ffff88007cb67ee8 0000000000000000 ffff88007bd8e000 0000000000000743
[    0.472340] Call Trace:
[    0.472340]  [<ffffffff8172f63d>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[    0.472340]  [<ffffffff8172a78d>] panic+0xc8/0x1d7
[    0.472340]  [<ffffffff8171f620>] ? rest_init+0x80/0x80
[    0.472340]  [<ffffffff8171f70e>] kernel_init+0xee/0xf0
[    0.472340]  [<ffffffff8174083c>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
[    0.472340]  [<ffffffff8171f620>] ? rest_init+0x80/0x80
[    0.472340] Kernel Offset: 0x0 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffff9fffffff)
```

Which shows a couple of errors.

I hope you could figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: wait, we've got no clue what your myimage.img contains; you obviously need to compile "hello, world" program and add it your images's filesystem.

Comment: @nadavgam You was pointed out to the problem by these lines in kernel log: `Failed to execute /bin/bash (error -2).  Attempting defaults...` and `Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/init.txt for guidance`. So either your ramdisk is broken or it doesn't contain `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @nadavgam Maybe [this](http://mgalgs.github.io/2015/05/16/how-to-build-a-custom-linux-kernel-for-qemu-2015-edition.html) link will help you to create working initramfs image for qemu.